# Mapping generic JSON field with Redshift Spectrum

Tags: hadoop, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to cast a variable type JSON field in Redshift Spectrum as a plane string but keep getting `column type VARCHAR for column STRUCT is incompatible`.

The JSON data I am trying to query has several fields which structure is fixed and expected. However there is one field with metadata which is a JSON with no specific format (anything is valid). For example:

```
{"fixed_integer": 1, "fixed_date": "2019-01-01", "metadata": {"one": "two", "three": 4}}
{"fixed_integer": 1, "fixed_date": "2019-01-01", "metadata": {"five": [1, 2], "six": false}}
```

I can map the code with the DDL as

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_data(
 fixed_integer int,
 fixed_date varchar,
 metadata varchar
)
```

without complaints, but when I try to query the data with a simple `SELECT metadata FROM my_data` I get

`declared column type VARCHAR for column STRUCT is incompatible`.

I could not find a workaround for it so far.
Have anyone faced a this or a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Metadata field it's not a valid varchar, to be a valid varchar field it should look like this

`"metadata": '{"one": "two", "three": 4}}'`

which is not a correct json format

I think if you create your external table with metadata as struct you can query it

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_data(
 fixed_integer int,
 fixed_date varchar,
 metadata struct <details:varchar(4000)>
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties (
'dots.in.keys' = 'true',
 as location '<s3 location>'
```

While you query metadata field you need to specify .

```
SELECT metadata.details FROM my_data
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @mdem7 for your answer. You can indeed query the `metadata` field as you said if you map the inner fields with in struct. The problem is that, in my use case, I don't know the fields in advance. They can be anything, so I need to query the whole field as a `varchar` for further processing down the the pipeline...

Comment: I think this is possible with Athena anyway. I could just define the `metadata` field as a `string` and then query it with Athena/Presto JSON functions. I thought there might be a way to do it in Spectrum too.